# pythonもしくはRで2行ずつの処理をする方法

Tags: python, r

独学でPython、Rを学んでいます。

```
        a       b       c       d       e       f       ...     x
ID_1    11      17      32      9       62      299     
ID_2    3       71      22      929     11      39      
ID_3    43      21      2       41      42      8       
ID_4    9       1       99      78      2       1
.
.
.
ID_X
```

上記のようなテーブルから、
a列が10以上の場合（ID_1, ID_3）のみa列×b列を計算、c列が10以上の場合（ID_1, ID_2, ID_4）のみc列×d列を計算、といった処理をしたいのですが、
うまい処理の方法がわかりません。
100行以上ある行、列で、自動で2列ずつ分割して判定、処理する方法はありませんでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

追記
書き方がわかりにくくて申し訳ありません。
f列以降の列も、ID_4以降の行も続く大きなテーブルでの処理です。
なので、a列の判定->計算、c列の判定->計算・・・といった個別の処理が出来なく、
うまい処理方法をご教示いただきたいです。

追記2

```
        a/b      c/d      e/f    ...     x
ID_1    0.6      3.6      0.2      
ID_2    NA       0.0      0.3       
ID_3    2.0      NA       5.3      
ID_4    NA       1.3      NA 
.
.
.
ID_X
```

イメージとしては、上記のようなアウトプットを想定しています。

現在、

> > odd <- DF[(0:(ncol(DF)%/%2)*2)+1]
>   > even <- DF[(0:(ncol(DF)%/%2)*2)]
>   > odd / even

とすることで、なんとか隣り合った列を計算させることはできましたが、
各偶数列が10以上の行のみ計算する方法がまだわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

Pythonでの例です。

前処理

```
PS C:\> python.exe
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> text = '''        a       b       c       d       e       f
... ID_1    11      17      32      9       62      299
... ID_2    3       71      22      929     11      39
... ID_3    43      21      2       41      42      8
... ID_4    9       1       99      78      2       1'''
>>> data = [x.split() for x in text.splitlines()]
>>> data
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['ID_1', '11', '17', '32', '9', '62', '299'], ['ID_2', '3', '71', '22', '929', '11', '39'], ['ID_3', '43', '21', '2', '41', '42', '8'], ['ID_4', '9', '1', '99', '78', '2', '1']]
>>> header = data.pop(0)
>>> header
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>>> data
[['ID_1', '11', '17', '32', '9', '62', '299'], ['ID_2', '3', '71', '22', '929', '11', '39'], ['ID_3', '43', '21', '2', '41', '42', '8'], ['ID_4', '9', '1', '99', '78', '2', '1']]
>>> header = ['index'] + header
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data,  columns=header, dtype=int)
>>> df = df.set_index(['index'])
>>> df
        a   b   c    d   e    f
index
ID_1   11  17  32    9  62  299
ID_2    3  71  22  929  11   39
ID_3   43  21   2   41  42    8
ID_4    9   1  99   78   2    1
```

aが10以上の行

```
>>> df[df.a>=10]
        a   b   c   d   e    f
index
ID_1   11  17  32   9  62  299
ID_3   43  21   2  41  42    8
```

aが10以上の行は、aとbを掛ける

```
>>> df[df.a>=10].apply(lambda s: s.a * s.b, axis=1)
index
ID_1    187
ID_3    903
dtype: int64
```

cが10以上の行は、cとdを掛ける

```
>>> df[df.c>=10].apply(lambda s: s.c * s.d, axis=1)
index
ID_1      288
ID_2    20438
ID_4     7722
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

欲しいアウトプットよく分かりませんが、Rで一つのやり方あげます：

```
#奇数列の索引
odd_col = seq(1L, ncol(DF), by = 2L)
lapply(odd_col, function(jj) {
  #適当な行を選ぶ
  idx = DF[[jj]] >= 10
  #これと隣の列をかける
  DF[[jj]][idx] * DF[[jj+1L]][idx]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandasの場合は、[::2]で2個飛ばしにできるので、次のように計算できます。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# サンプルデータ
df = pd.DataFrame([[11, 17, 32, 9, 62, 299],
             [3, 71, 22, 929, 11, 39],
             [43, 21, 2, 41, 42, 8],
             [9, 1, 99, 78, 2, 1]],
             columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

# a, c, e,...列をとる
df1 = df.iloc[:,::2]
# b, d, f,...列をとる
df2 = df.iloc[:,1::2]
# 10以上の場合に計算する。ここでは割り算をしています
df1[df1 >= 10] / np.array(df2)
```